# ZSH Snippets - Multiple Placeholder?

Tags: zsh

I am trying to emulate the behaviour of ultisnips with zsh, mainly the feature of having multiple place holders. For example, I use taskwarrior a lot but always with the same structure:

```
taskwarrior add p:PROJECT due:DATE TASKDescription
```

To speed ups things I wanted to have a snippet that with a key (e.g., "tadd") expands to:

```
taskwarrior add p: due:
```

with the placeholder after "p:" and when I press a key (e.g., ctrl+j) jumps to the next placeholder, i.e., after "due:". In Ultisnips I can do:

```
snippet tadd "Taskwarrio" b
taskwarrior add p:$1 due:$2 $3
endsnippet
```

Any idea of how to it in ZSH?

Comment: do you need the slots and jumping about or would a `function tadd { taskwarrior add p:$1 due:$2 $3 }` suffice?

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/Paris/IronAHK could accomplish the same objective.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression you want a function like in any Bourne-like shell:

defined like:

```
tadd() taskwarrior add p:$1 due:$2 $3
```

To be invoked as:

```
tadd PROJECT DATE TASKDescription
```

Comment: well, that for sure would work but it is not what I wanted. I wanted to actually expand the command and edit it as I find appropriated. Moreover, snippets are much more flexible than functions but if we do not have the multiple placeholders in ZSH it is not so useful...

Comment: @user2801023, you can use `t:` in vi mode to jump to the next `:` (or Ctrl+S : in emacs mode) assuming that's what you mean by _placeholder_.